# Pushing updates to my premium WordPress theme

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm about to set my first premium WordPress theme on the market. I will sell it through my own website. But I'm wondering how I can push updates through to the people who buy my theme? What is best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to sell it using WooCommerce, the [WooCommerce API Manager](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-api-manager/) extension will manage license keys, and will allow you you to push updates to users with valid license keys.  It also adds license management functions to your customers account, allowing them to manage their licenses themselves.  Also, if you also use the [Subscriptions](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) extension, you can send notices to customers to notify them about an expiring license, and encourage them to renew their license.

You may also find similar features if you choose to sell your theme using the Easy Digital Downloads plugin for WordPress, and use the Software Licensing extension for license management.

Both of these solutions involve premium plugin extensions, and will cost you a little bit of cash.

Comment: Just the answer I needed! Thanks @JShipC :)